# "This question exists because it has historical significance"...uhh, that's great, but that's an answer

Tags: bug, post-notices

While [visiting one of the most impressive pilgrimage sites in the holy lands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), I noticed a lost banner floating [beneath one of the most awesome answers of all times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/180239).

[image: A picture outlining stuff.]

So, is it supposed to float underneath the answer, and if yes, is it supposed to say "question"?

Comment: The notice means that particular post is exempt from SO quality standards. So being picky about the notice text is kind of redundant.

Comment: yeah it is a bug ... minor ... but still a bug

Comment: @mario: Well, to be honest, I'm just trying to find stuff I can draw freehand circles, lines and arrows to. ;P

Comment: @mario That is *not* what that banner means.  *No* post is exempt from the quality standards of SO/Stack Exchange for *any* reason.  That banner means "oops, we messed up by letting this exist at one time and if we did something we know you'll have our heads so we won't outright delete it".  It's the only thing we can apply to *answers* right now.  Questions should *not* be locked for historical purposes anymore, for questions "closed" is the new "lock for historical significance" (yes, closing a post locks it, but you get the point) to indicate that it is *not* appropriate for the site.

Comment: Can we get a mod to unlock that answer again?

Comment: For what it's worth, this was previously closed as a dupe of [The historical significance lock reason on answers still references "this question"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108404/the-historical-significance-lock-reason-on-answers-still-references-this-questi) (which is now deleted)

Answer (score 4):

It's not really a bug, a moderator added that notice *to the answer*, and not to the question. You can see that in  [the post history of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/revisions). Though you're right that the notice probably should be added to the question instead.

Comment: Arrrr...I didn't even look into the post history. Guess that turns it into a "pluralization" bug...well, without the pluralization, just with a question/answer mix up...I wonder if Jeff also has giant Qs and As for that...

Comment: See my comment on the question, "locked for historical" significance should *not* be used anymore, "close" (which has the effect of lock) should be used to indicate the content is *not* appropriate.