# Is it possible to 'cheat' the First Posts review queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

Out of interest I just followed the following steps in the First Posts review queue:

1. Visited the page to load an answer for review
2. Up-voted the answer
3. Opened the full URL to the question in a new tab
4. Clicked 'I'm done' in the review queue
5. Refreshed the full question page in the other tab, and removed my up-vote.

When I checked the review history for First Posts my review was (unsurprisingly) still there.

As I understand it the number of First Post reviews a user is allowed to carry in a day is directly linked to the number of votes they have remaining that day.

With that in mind, wouldn't it be quite easy for a user to follow the above process in an effort to earn badges more easily and 'cheat' the daily limit? Or are there other checks in place?

Comment: The sad thing is, that sort of cheating would actually be an improvement over how _some_ people use that queue.

Comment: Reviewing is not for the badges, so cheating is not needed. (at least in a perfect world).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Steward Badge gaming visible in the Review Close Queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148018/steward-badge-gaming-visible-in-the-review-close-queue)

Comment: The only thing common between these questions is they are about cheating. They are about two completely different cases, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, actually.  You're still limited to 20 first post reviews per day.  Doing what you have described would only allow you to vote on 40 posts outside of the review queue while still doing 20 reviews (assuming you are unwilling to edit/close vote/comment/flag in the review queue).

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense thanks